# Maven Release Plugin with GIT: pom.xml configuration

Tags: java, maven, maven-release-plugin

I've been trying to find a example of how to configure the maven-release-plugin, but to now luck I haven't been able to find a full example of a already configured pom.xml. The Maven website doesn't off much in terms of examples and I am a very visual learner. A link or an example mock pom.xml with a the maven-release-plugin would be most helpful.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to define the version of maven-release-plugin via pluginManagement. Then next step is to define the SCM information in your pom like this:

```xml
 <scm>
    <connection>scm:git:https://github.com/jenkinsci/java-client-api.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://git@github.com/jenkinsci/java-client-api.git</developerConnection>
    <url>https://github.com/jenkinsci/java-client-api</url>
  </scm>
```

The given information is just as an example and you need to change to your requirements.

BTW: What is about this: http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/usage.html

Comment: Not to be rude, but that wasn't really that helpful. I've already looked at the doc for the usage of the plugin. I need more a full example, defining the plugin configuration in the build section in the pom. How to configure the plugin to create tags from a specific branch. if this is not possible the least I would like to is how to auto increment the version number on every release build.